# Saving CLCircularRegion with Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm working on an app using Parse and geofencing. I have a geofence object that looks like this:

Geofence.h -->

```
@interface Geofence : PFObject<PFSubclassing>
+ (NSString *) parseClassName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CLCircularRegion * region;

@end
```

Gefence.m -->

```
#import "Geofence.h"
#import <Parse/PFObject+Subclass.h>

@implementation Geofence

+ (void) load {
    [self registerSubclass];
}

+ (NSString *)parseClassName {
    return @"Geofence";
}

@dynamic region;

@end
```

In my AddGeofenceClass, I set the geofence by calling my private method setUpGeofence:

```
self.region = [self setUpGeofence:self.longitude.doubleValue:self.latitude.doubleValue];
```

self.region is being set correctly, but when I try to set the region object with Parse here:

```
[self.geofence setObject:self.region forKey:@"region"];
```

I get the error:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'PFObject values may not have class: CLCircularRegion'

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure that Parse supports any object type. My guess is that you have to save a CLLocation object and a radius value, then recreate your CLCircularRegion using them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot put any object type in Parse. If I made a class called "MyClass," I couldn't just say:

```
[self.parseObject setObject:instanceOfMyClass forKey:@"MyClass"];
```

Parse wouldn't know how to handle it. What I would suggest doing is saving the center point in a PFGeoPoint using:

```
PFGeoPoint *point = [PFGeoPoint geoPointWithLatitude:yourRegionsCenterLatitude longitude:yourRegionsCenterLongitude];
[self.parseObject setObject:point forKey:@"CenterPoint"];
```

Then you can have another column in Parse called "Radius" that you can save  in another column that is of Number type like so:

```
[self.parseObject setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:regionRadiusAsFloat] forKey:@"Radius"];
```

And then you can retrieve them later in a query and reconstruct the region using the center and the radius.